# Generating 5V DC in an AC system without the neutral wire

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, ac, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

This is my first foray into AC circuits, I've only worked in low voltage DC circuits before.

I am building an AC dimmer circuit with a wireless radio, a bit like [this device](https://www.thesmartshop.co.uk/lightwaverf/store/home-automation-lighting/jsjslw420ss-lightwaverf-2-gang-light-dimmer-switch-in-stainless-steel) and I don't quite understand how I can generate a 5V DC voltage without the neutral wire being present.

The AC to DC converter module I use requires both a live and a neutral wire connected:

[image]

In the [product linked above](https://www.thesmartshop.co.uk/lightwaverf/store/home-automation-lighting/jsjslw420ss-lightwaverf-2-gang-light-dimmer-switch-in-stainless-steel) they must have some form of DC voltage present for the radio circuitry, I am guessing.

How would I go about either wiring the AC-DC module without the presence of a neutral wire and failing/ditching that, what kind of a power circuitry I would need to get5V DC with just the Live wire being present?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think they don't have a neutral going in? I can clearly see it in the diagram you posted. Pin 3.

Comment: You can't build anything with only the live wire, circuits work because well, they go in kind of a circle...

Comment: @pipe That is the wiring diagram for the AC to DC converter module I am currently using in my prototype, not for the product I have linked to. This is from their datasheet: "NOTE: LightwaveRF dimmers do NOT require a mains neutral wire to be connected; they only require ‘live in’ and ‘switched live out’."

Comment: ...unless you are in a 3-phase system, but if that is the case it is probably best to gently suggest that you are in over your head.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Evidently, hence the question :) In this case I am looking at a single phase installation, though.

Comment: Oh, dimmers of that sort get their return through the load.  They use special purpose supplies which you should not try to duplicate without a lot more background.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am more interested in understanding/learning about how it all works than actually building it at this point so can you perhaps point me at some literature about how this "return through the load" mechanism works? Thanks.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, as you can see from the comments and answers it is possible to steal power to power an in-line circuit. Industrial two-wire proximity switches are another example where the sensor is powered whether its output is on or off.

Comment: @transistor: no, the situation mentioned there is different, the connection to the neutral is made *through the load*. It is impossible to plug a live wire into a wall outlet and power a circuit without any way of completing the circuit through to the N/GND point.

Comment: I think he understands that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a device that operates in series with a load and must draw it's power from this series connection while turning the load on and off. How do we do that?

When the load is "on" we allow a small voltage drop across our control device. We have a small voltage but lots of current which provides us with the power we need.

When the load is off we allow a small current in the circuit. Now we have a small current but lots of voltage and again we get the power we need.

Note that this approach does have some issues.

1. The power circuit design will likely be quite complex. It will need to operate under two VERY different sets of conditions, high voltage but low current and low voltage but high current.
2. The power needed by the control device must be much smaller than the power the load consumes.
3. The Load must have suitable characteristics. It's voltage/current relationship must be suitable and it must not be adversely affected by small currents flowing when things are nominally turned off. Incandescent light bulbs were fine but CFL and LED bulbs can be more problematic.

Answer (score 3):

Further to Peter Green's post, one such circuit popular since the 1980s was a touch-dimmer based on the 8-pin CMOS IC TT8486A/TT6061A. This schematic will give you some idea how the type of circuit you're looking for could be managed.

As Peter says, you have to be careful that when your switch is closed that you still drop enough voltage to power the device. In the triac controlled applications it probably means that the load won't be switched on until the voltage across the triac reaches around 20 V. The lamp voltage will be reduced and will no longer be a sine wave.

http://www.electroschematics.com/2353/touch-dimmer-switch-circuit/